# Algebraic structure with more than $2$ internal laws?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

This is probably a stupid question but could there be an algebraic structure like a group or a ring or something else, with more than $2$ internal laws? like $(G,+,\cdot,\star)$?

I know we could create an additional law on $\Bbb Z$ for example by defining $a\star b=a+b-ab$ or something but that uses the two already existing laws...

Do we study $(\Bbb F[x],+,\cdot,\circ)$ as a structure addition multiplication and composition of polynomials?

Comment: An algebra has three operations.

Comment: Vector spaces ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of an extra internal law defined from existing internal laws, it's the commutator.

Fix a ring $R$. The commutator of $R$ is the antisymmetric product given by
$$[a,b]=ab-ba$$
for two elements $a,b\in R$. One can check that this operation acts as a derivative, meaning that it satisfies Leibniz rule,
$$[a,bc]=[a,b]c+b[a,c];$$
and it satisfies the axioms of a Lie algebra product

- $[a+b,c]=[a,c]+[b,c]$
- $[a,a]=0$
- (Jacobi identity) $[a,[b,c]]+[b,[c,a]]+[c,[a,b]]=0$

In this way, $(R,+,[\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,])$ becomes a Lie algebra, which is used to understand the commutativity of the original ring $R$.

Answer (score 1):

The structure $(\Bbb F[x],+,\cdot,\circ)$ is an example of a [composition ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_ring).